# How to make android app to fit for all screen sizes

Tags: android

Well i have activity.xml i which i have a background image and a button which also has a background image in it run well on normal screen but when i run it on xlarge or large screen the position of button changes

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/my_view_margin"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:background="@drawable/bt"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the code above and below are the images of different screen

cant add images cause doesnt have enough reputation

Comment: For starters, you would want to start using `dp` values instead of `px` values. And, read up on these links. More than enough to achieve what you are looking for. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: These links will help you to create application for multiple screens : 1. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html 2. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html These are android's official documents on implementing support for multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 5):

Use weight for all layouts instead of giving constant values, Because weight is a type of % for screen.In manifest by default support screen view is true.

and if any times you think, It's not possible than add dimens values {folder contains dimens.xml}

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/my_view_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bt"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layouts, draw 9 images. And for high quality apps you may create different different layout XMLS for all 4 screen sizes.http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Use this link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use relative layout with the set margin code. Set the margins between each text view, button, etc and it will look the same on every phone.

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
// change Top to Bottom, Left or Right for what you need.
```